# Handling Android's SQLiteException

Tags: java, android, sql, sqlite, exception

I'm trying to make my SQLite Database interactions in my Android code more robust.

On of my tables has one column that is marked as `UNIQUE`. Now I want to handle the case that my application tries to enter a non-unique entry. To achieve that I use the method `SQLiteDatabase.insertOrThrow()`. That method throws an `android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException`. Unfortunately that exception doesn't allow me to get the error code (like `java.sql.SQLException` kindly does).
So in my catch-block I have no way of handling the exception error-code-sensitive, am I correct?

What is best practice to handle `SQLiteExceptions` on Android? Can my application really just say there's a problem but not find out what the problem is?

Thank you for your help and time.
Dan

Comment: There are also other conflict handling mechanisms than `throw`. See e.g `insertWithOnConflict()`. There's no single "best practice", it depends on your particular case. Could you clarify your question to be more specific? Thanks.

Comment: Thanks for your comment laalto, my question is if there's a way to get the error-code, returned from SQLite, from SQLiteException. Roy Dictus pointed me to the subclasses like SQLiteConstraintException which basically translate to the error codes. So my question is answered :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you can do in this particular case, is to verify whether the record you are about to insert will indeed be unique. That way you can avoid inserting a non-unique value and this issue is no longer an issue.

That being said, a number of specific exceptions inherit from `SQLiteException`, such as `SQLiteConstraintException`. You can also catch the specific ones and do what you must.

Comment: Thank you, I overlooked the subclasses. They make the error-handling easier. And I think I'm going to go with your advice to check if my entry is unique before I insert it.

Comment: How can one check the uniqueness of the new entry? I mean for checking the uniqueness one need to search through previous records and that means we need to run an extra query per insertion. Is there any way in which we can get the source of exception that occur and pin point it to unique constraint violation. In that way we dont need to do check before insertion.

Comment: @smasher, if a column is marked UNIQUE and it is indexed, the extra search for a row with that column value is quick. It is also the easiest and most surefire way to avoid duplicates.